# Why don't flex items shrink past content size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 4 flexbox columns and everything works fine, but when I add some text to a column and set it to a big font size, it is making the column wider than it should be due to the flex property.

I tried to use `word-break: break-word` and it helped, but still when I resize the column to a very small width, letters in the text are broken into multiple lines (one letter per line), and yet the column does not get smaller width than one letter size.

Watch this [video](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDetln1tyT)
(at the start, the first column is the smallest, but when I resized the window, it is the widest column. I just want to respect flex settings always; flex sizes 1 : 3 : 4 : 4)

I know, setting font-size and column padding to smaller will help... but is there any other solution?

I can not use `overflow-x: hidden`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78h8wv4o/3/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%
}
.col {
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
  word-break: break-word
}
.col1 {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 80px
}
.col2 {
  flex: 3;
  background: yellow
}
.col3 {
  flex: 4;
  background: skyblue
}
.col4 {
  flex: 4;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col col1">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="col col2">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="col col4">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1037, accepted):

#### The Automatic Minimum Size of Flex Items

You're encountering a flexbox default setting.

*A flex item cannot be smaller than the size of its content along the main axis.*

The defaults are...

- `min-width: auto`
- `min-height: auto`

...for flex items in row-direction and column-direction, respectively.

You can override these defaults by setting flex items to:

- `min-width: 0`
- `min-height: 0`
- `overflow: hidden` (or any other value, except `visible`)

---

#### Flexbox Specification

> [**4.5. Automatic Minimum Size of Flex
>   Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)
>
> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for flex items, this
>   specification introduces a new `auto` value as the initial value of
>   the `min-width` and `min-height` properties defined in CSS 2.1.

*With regard to the `auto` value...*

> On a flex item whose `overflow` is `visible` in the main axis, when specified on the flex item’s main-axis min-size property, specifies an *automatic minimum size*. It otherwise computes to `0`.

In other words:

- The `min-width: auto` and `min-height: auto` defaults apply only when `overflow` is `visible`.
- If the `overflow` value is not `visible`, the value of the min-size property is `0`.
- Hence, `overflow: hidden` can be a substitute for `min-width: 0` and `min-height: 0`.

and...

- The minimum sizing algorithm applies only on the main axis.
- For example, a flex item in a row-direction container does not get `min-height: auto` by default.
- For a more detailed explanation see this post:

  - [min-width rendering differently in flex-direction: row and flex-direction: column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40407619/3597276)

---

#### You've applied min-width: 0 and the item still doesn't shrink?

*Nested Flex Containers*

If you're dealing with flex items on multiple levels of the HTML structure, it may be necessary to override the default `min-width: auto` / `min-height: auto` on items at higher levels.

Basically, a higher level flex item with `min-width: auto` can prevent shrinking on items nested below with `min-width: 0`.

Examples:

- [Flex item is not shrinking smaller than its content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47456839/3597276)
- [Fitting child into parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44826555/3597276)
- [white-space css property is creating issues with flex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49897730/3597276)

---

#### Browser Rendering Notes

- *Chrome vs. Firefox / Edge*

  Since at least 2017, it appears that Chrome is either (1) reverting back to the `min-width: 0` / `min-height: 0` defaults, or (2) automatically applying the `0` defaults in certain situations based on a mystery algorithm. (This could be what they call an [**intervention**](https://github.com/WICG/interventions).) As a result, many people are seeing their layout (especially desired scrollbars) work as expected in Chrome, but not in Firefox / Edge. This issue is covered in more detail here: [flex-shrink discrepancy between Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49575838/3597276)
- *IE11*

  As noted in the spec, the `auto` value for the `min-width` and `min-height` properties is "new". This means that some browsers may still render a `0` value by default, because they implemented flex layout before the value was updated and because `0` is the initial value for `min-width` and `min-height` in [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths). [One such browser is IE11.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052987/flexbox-flex-basis-0px-in-chrome) Other browsers have updated to the newer `auto` value as defined in the [flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto).

---

#### Revised Demo

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 30px;
  word-break: break-word
}

.col1 {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
  font-size: 80px;
  min-width: 0;   /* NEW */
}

.col2 {
  flex: 3;
  background: yellow
}

.col3 {
  flex: 4;
  background: skyblue
}

.col4 {
  flex: 4;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col col1">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="col col2">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="col col3">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="col col4">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78h8wv4o/4/)

Comment: Looks like Chrome changed the behavior in v73 to not shrink smaller than the content.

Comment: Same fix worked with `min-height: 0;` . I had to try setting this for several higher elements in the tree.

Comment: I had to set `min-height: 0;` in ike 10 places to get it to work. Thank you, thank you, thank you for the great tip!

Comment: @dave0688, maybe an overall reset would be simpler: `* { min-height: 0; }`

Comment: @maccam94 it would be against the purpose of a browser to hide, destroy, distort or otherwise show in an incomplete manner the original information

Comment: I still don't know when we should  add `min-width:0`, for the  example above, resize the window to small and the `.col1` has a width of **0**, but we can still see the character, can someone provide a example that makes more sense?

Comment: You simply solved my problem just by describing the nesting flex shrinking behaviour. THANK YOU

Comment: For me the need to set `min-width: 0` was only necessary in Chrome. In Firefox it all worked fine.

Comment: What if, a child element is not intended to shrink below 400px height, and doesn't once min-height is set to 400px, but since the parents has been set a min-height of 0, the parents still shrink resulting in some sort over overflow of the child ? how could you solve this if you've set a lot of "min-height: 0px" on parent containers ? is there some way to bubble up the child min-height constraint to the parents ?

Comment: @AxelSamyn, this should be posted as a full question, with code that reproduces the scenario.

Answer (score 29):

I'm finding this has bitten me repeatedly over the years for both flex and grid, so I'm going to suggest the following:

```
* { min-width: 0; min-height: 0; }
```

and then just use `min-width: auto` or `min-height: auto` if you need that behaviour.

In fact, throw in box-sizing as well to make all layout more sane:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; min-width: 0; min-height: 0; }
```

Does anyone know if there are any odd consequences? I've not encountered anything in several years of using a mix of the above. In fact, I can't think of any cases where I'd want to layout from content outwards to the flex/grid, rather than flex/grid inwards to the content --- and surely if they exist, they're rare. So this feels like a bad default. But maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: yes, the side effect is the shadow dom and slotted elements, which now required !important if you want to change this default min-width.

Comment: Btw, for the web component case, the trick is to use css var. This way, you have default value, but can be overridden, while still have the * { mid-width: ..} above. 

:host{
  --min-width: 10rem;
  min-width: var(--min-width) !important;
  ...
}


and then, in app.css you can have 

c-menu{
 --min-width: 30rem;
}

Comment: Your suggested default settings (`0`) used to be the flex defaults (consistent with the rest of CSS). There are reasons for modifying the spec from `0` to `auto`. You may want to consider these reasons before switching them back. If you're interested in the details, start here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin, Curiously, I'd say the spec provides better reasons to avoid content-based minimums. Nevertheless, the main point they make in its favour is that it is "often appropriate, and helps prevent content from overlapping or spilling outside its container" --- but is that needed more often than outside-in layout? My own experience has suggested otherwise and `min-<dim>: 0' hasn't caused me any issues yet, but I acknowledge the (practical) issue with web components @JeremyChone mentions. If you had more links on the reasoning, would be happy to check them out.

Comment: @voracity - This post currently has nearly 64K views and the accepted answer is closing in on 600 upvotes. Even closed duplicates of this question (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38382734/3597276) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43809612/3597276)) have tens of thousands of views and hundreds of upvotes. So, yeah, this issue may need to be revisited by spec authors.

Comment: For the record, these default settings apply in Grid layout, as well. https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#min-size-auto

Answer (score 2):

For this code below, adding `width: 100%` solved my problem.

```css
.post-cover .inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    word-break: break-all;
    z-index: 21;
}
.post-cover .article-page {
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    line-height: 2.0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;   /* Add this */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**The pure answer to your question is that by default, browsers tend to display as much information as possible to the reader (and not to hide anything).**

That happens by default, and even includes showing default black color fonts on a white background (for maximum page contrast and readability), adding a scroll bar where content is larger than the viewport height (or width) or still showing content from a markup (or the background color) even if this was mistakenly placed after `</body>` or even `</html>` tags in the html file.

In context of CSS, this applies as well, but you also are allowed to play with many customizations on top of that.

Even in a screen if using a huge font (like `font-size: 50em;`) this initially acts as an overflowing element (and placing the font inside a flexible child container by using `display: flex` doesn't change this default behaviour unless you use `overflow: hidden` or resize the element in some way.

An elegant solution is to use a dynamic resizing of the letters, for example

`font-size: calc(0.5em + 2vw)`

which works great even in a responsive scenario.

As a previous answer mentioned, *A flex item cannot be smaller than the size of its content along the main axis* (for the same reason, that is not only specific to the flexbox model implemented in CSS but because of the inner browser way of working). Even a long word is displayed with a scrollbar if it's longer than display width as if being a block type element with a fixed size instead.

This is mentioned in old html 4.01 specifications as

> "By convention, visual HTML user agents wrap text lines to fit within
> the available margins. Wrapping algorithms depend on the script being
> formatted.
>
> In Western scripts, for example, text should only be wrapped at white
> space. "

as seen [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html) in paragraph 9.5.3. This means that, since then, the text had to be continuously displayed by default (unless we decide to split it but not at single character level: a single non-white character shown at 120em size will trigger scrollbars displaying on the browser).

Words are also clearly defined in paragraph 9.1 in the same source:

> we use the term "word" here to mean "sequences of non-white space
> characters"

The purpose of displaying the original format of any word is to not destroy, hide or distort the original information, the meaning or intent of the code author. As such, we also have `&nbsp;` for keeping in same line two words that are connected - when breaking them might be disruptive (such as New York, 10 PM, 10 km/h, § 10, etc)

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 420px;
}

.child-with-ellipses {
  flex-basis: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.child-without-ellipses {
  flex-basis: 69%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-with-ellipses">
    This node has the class `child-with-ellipses`.
  </div>
  <div class="child-without-ellipses"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The most efficient solution as for now is using `-webkit-line-clamp`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-line-clamp

You can specify number of lines to preserve, for example 1.

Old solution based on `min-width: 0` does not work on complex layouts with wide usage of `flex`.

Answer (score -3):

I tried everything, even putting the below code in the index.css.

```
* {
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But nothing worked.

finally I made the div I wanted to shrink past it's content to have `position: absolute;`. Then it started shrinking.
It's parent div would need a defined height and width. This might not be the best solution for every scenario but if this works for you, good!

Comment: answer has nothing to do with flex items shrinking, as now the items are not flex items